# Storage to serve assets for Toloka.ai tasks

Tags: toloka

Is there a way to serve files for tasks (like images) not only from Yandex Disk?
I think disk is OK only for start because it's personal and limited to 10 GB

Answer (score 0):

Additionally to [Yandex Disk](https://yandex.com/support/toloka-requester/concepts/prepare-data.html) you can use Yandex.Cloud for uploading images. Looks like that these are all possible options (according to the doc) https://yandex.com/support/toloka-requester/concepts/use-object-storage.html